# Logical AND two float values in PHP (32 bit)

Tags: php, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I logical AND two float values in PHP (v5.4.3)?

```
$a = 16710107135;
$b = 4294967296;
$result = (float)$a & (float)$b;
echo $result;
```

The above will always show 0 but actually should show 4294967296.
I have also tried to "settype" all variables to float but with the same result.

If relevant then it is running on a 64 bit Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS 7.5 and PHP is 32 bit.

Comment: I'm not sure whether logical `AND` is defined on floats. Are you expecting a result as if they were integers or as their binary representation were bitwise `AND`ed?

Comment: @Joachim - I would expect it to return 4294967296 and not 0.

Comment: `&&` maybe, not `&` for [*logical*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) `AND` ?

Comment: For me `$result` is `4294967296`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operator first converts its parameters to integers, then performs the operation. In other words, your float casts are immediately converted back to integers.

4294967296 cast to a 32 bit integer overflows to 0, so the result of the `&` operation is 0.

If you're running on a 64-bit machine, the value fits in a 64 bit integer and gives the expected result, 4294967296.

EDIT: If you need more bits of precision than the "bitness" of the machine, you can compile PHP with [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) and use those functions.

Comment: I am running on a 64 bit machine but as the PHP is 32 bit (no 64 bit for Windows), then I always get 0 as result. Are there other ways of setting this value to anything but 0 (I just need it **not** to be 0)?

Comment: @user2028935 If you need more bits of precision than the "bitness" of the machine, you can compile PHP with [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) and use those functions.

Comment: Joachim - please suggest this as an answer as it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @user2028935 Added GMP to the answer.